# ReBake a fluid Simulation?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Following problem: I have a fluid animation which works after being baked. Now I  change some detail, the inflow velocity or the inflow type for example, but when I hit the bake button again the status bar runs from 0-100% really fast, but my fluid-animation does nothing at all afterwards. The "old animation" has gone, but no new one appeared.
The only solution I found so far is to completely delete the domain, add a new one, make all settings again and bake then...

Is anyone able to help me finding an easier solution?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely because you did not change the location of the fluid bake. Set the fluid bake location to an empty file on your computer separate from the other bake, and try again.